# AWS Lambda function with Timer blocks concurrency

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I am developing a Lambda function in python that sends emails when elements in DynamoDB are updated. When a element in DynamoDB is updated to a specific value, I want to wait for 5 minutes and then send the email. The problem is that, when the lambda function is waiting those 5 minutes, if I make a change in another element in DynamoDB, another lambda instance should be created and executed in parallel, but it executes when the 5 minutes of the first lambda are over, not executing in parallel. Sometimes it doesn't even execute.

I have tried implementing the timer with time.sleep() and creating a thread threading.Timer() and waiting on a loop until the callback function updates a variable. Both of them have the same problem, while waiting the lambda "blocks" other lambda instanes.

Summary:
I have this lines of code in a lambda funcion:

```
timer = th.Timer(60, callBackFunction)
timer.start()
while disconnected == None:
    pass
```

So, the program waits on a loop until the callBackFunction, after timer is over, updates 'disconnected' variable and gets out of the loop. This works fine, but while the lambda is on the loop waiting for the timer to be over, other lambda instances (of the same function) are triggered but they are being executed after the timer is over, where I expect to execute in parallel because of concurrency

Thanks very much everyone

Comment: Why do you need to wait 5 minutes before sending the email?

Comment: The lambda is triggered when a device disconnection is registered in a DynamoDB table. I need to wait 5 minutes and, if the device is still disconnected, I send the email. The reason is that the device disconnects and connects very often but for a short period of time, and i don't want to send mails in that case, only if the device is still disconnected after 5 minutes.

Comment: Might be worth reconsidering how you're doing this. Perhaps you could record the disconnects in DynamoDB and simply run a Lambda function on a schedule (every 5 or 10 minutes, for example) that queries for '5min+ disconnected devices' and it then sends the notifications (also possibly worth doing that via SNS to email rather than SES directly).

Answer (score 1):

I don't want to go into too much detail about how your use-case is an anti-pattern, you should probably look into using Event Bridge Pipes with your DynamoDB Stream.

However, for your specific use case, your DynamoDB partition has a 1:1 mapping with a stream's shard which also has a 1:1 mapping with a Lambda container. Given that you update the same item, it will end up on the same partition -> shard -> Lambda container ( but you've put this container to sleep ).

You *may* be able to overcome your issue by increasing the parallelization factor of your event source mapping, this will allow multiple Lambda containers to act on a single shard. But you'd need to test to be sure.

Comment: Hello Lee, thanks for your response. Actually the problem appears when I update a different item (when I update the same item works fine). So when I update one item, the Lambda triggered waits for another Lambda (triggered because I updated a different item).

Comment: You likely only have 1 partition, which means you have 1 shard, and thus a single lambda container. Increase paralleization and let me know if it works.